# The electric field inside a conductor and Gauss' law

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law

The electric field inside a conductor must be zero. Can this be explained with the help of Gauss's law?

Also, how does this explain that if we have a conducting sphere with a cavity inside, and we place a point charge (say positive,  at the centre of this cavity) then there is a negative charged induced on the inner surface of this sphere, and a positive charge induced on the outer surface of the sphere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be explained using gauss's law, if you assume that charge on conductors reside on its surface.

You could take a random gaussian surface inside the conductor and use gauss's law i.e.
$$\oint \vec E \cdot d \vec A = \cfrac{q_{inside}}{\epsilon_0}$$ 
Since all the charge on the conductor resides on surface of the conductor $q_{inside} = 0$.
$$\therefore \oint \vec E \cdot d \vec A = \cfrac{0}{\epsilon_0} = 0$$
Since area of conductor isn't zero $\vec E = 0$.

https://www.autodraw.com/share/P4LIP8SS976M